# ImportError: cannot import name 'Data' from 'skcriteria'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error while trying to import from skcriteria:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
from skcriteria import Data, MIN, MAX

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13768/3629248265.py in <module>
      3 import seaborn as sns
      4 from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
----> 5 from skcriteria import Data, MIN, MAX
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ImportError: cannot import name 'Data' from 'skcriteria'
```

I am using python 3.9.7.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `Data` was replaced with `DecisionMatrix` in [version 0.5](https://github.com/quatrope/scikit-criteria/releases/tag/0.5):

> - The `Data` object was removed in favor of `DecisionMatrix` which implements many more useful features for MCDA.

Try importing `DecisionMatrix` instead:

```
from skcriteria import DecisionMatrix, MIN, MAX
```

I'm not sure about `MIN` and `MAX`, as they seem to have been removed as well.

Perhaps you can try this:

```
from skcriteria.preprocessing.scalers import MaxScaler, MinMaxScaler
```

Comment: Hi, skcriteria author here. Yes, data was replaced by "DecisionMatrix" (this is because the rankings and kernels are also "data").

MIN and MAX still exists, but you can directly use the functions "min" and "max" as a more easy alternative, example

`skcriteria.mkdm( matrix=[ [7, 5, 35], [5, 4, 26]], objectives=[max, max, min])`